# Using C macros in eclipse post-build step

Tags: c, eclipse, post-build

This question has been asked before (there are questions that are 5 or 10 years old) but without any real answer, usually a different approach has been used.

I'm working on a project where a different approach is simply not possible. We are using a third-party post-build step that needs some arguments (version) as part of the input. The version is set inside the C code using `#define` as some settings are set based on different parts of the version.

After some major changes, we have to recompile the code with different versions so I rather keep the version in a single location (in `main.h` preferably). Is there any way to do it in eclipse or do I have to bear the pain and just change it at multiple locations manually?

I'm using Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3), since I'm using system workbench and that's their default version.

Comment: do not do it in the .h file. Define the symbol in the eclipse and pass it as -D parameter to the gcc.

Comment: @P__J__ Is there a reason why I shouldn't put it in the .h file or is it just easier to put it in the symbols? Because the symbols of release and debug are different, putting it there means I should change it in two places.

Comment: The advantage of including the version information in a header is that you can version control the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `-D` parameter (in project properties > C/C++ Build > settings > Tool Settings > Preprocessor) did not do the job for me as the macros or the build variables defined based on them were not expanding in the post-build step.

My workaround was to write a shell script to read the version from the header file and then pass it to the post-build. So I'm calling the other script inside my script that extracts the version. This way I can change the versions inside the code rather than the labyrinth of the eclipse settings.

This line extracts the version:

`fw_version=$(cat "$projectdir/../Inc/main.h" | grep "FW_VERSION" | cut -d ' ' -f 3-)`

Answer (score 0):

You have some tool that does:

1. Your build
2. This post build step

Extract the version `#define` from your C project (in 1) and store it instead in a build system variable.  Then pass it as a `-D` parameter to the necessary files (in 1), and as a parameter in whatever way it's expected by step 2.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? How to extract it from my C code and I'm not sure how to pass it as a `-D` parameter.